# C# Multiple programs in one install file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, setup-project

I have created 6 POS and Inventory programs, one for each business type like Electronics store, Fashion, Pharmacy, Restaurants.

is there a way to create one setup file which the user can select which business type he wants to install? instead of creating 6 setup files one for each project?

Comment: What kind of installer technology have you tried?

Comment: just installshield

Comment: You might want to look into having an installer with multiple features, which the user can select during the installation.

Comment: This works for selecting default program language as well?

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest.